# Norm of an element in a finite field

Tags: finite-fields

Let $\mathbb{F}_p =:K\leqslant F:=\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$.
Define the norm of $f\in F$ to be $N_{F/K}(f) = f^{p^{n-1}+p^{n-2}+\ldots +p+1}$

> Show that if $f\in\mbox{ker}N$, then $f = g^{p-1}$, for some $g\in F^\times$

One can verify that the norm is always an element of $K$.
We also know that $N(f^p) = N(f)$ and the book [R. Lidl, H. Niederreiter, Finite Fields] says the implication is obvious [analogous to necessity in Thm 2.25 p.56].

Is it obvious? We have $N(f^p)=N(f)=1$ i.e
$$(f^p)^{(p^n-1)/(p-1)} = f^{(p^n-1)/(p-1)}=1 $$
how do  I explicitly get $g$ here, it's obvious, after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $\gamma \colon F^\times \to F^\times$, $f \mapsto f^{p-1}$.  Then $\def\im{\mathop{\rm im}}\im \gamma \subseteq \ker N$. Now 
$$f\in \ker \gamma \iff f^{p-1} = 1 \iff f^p = f \iff f \in K^\times $$
that is $\ker \gamma = K^\times$. Hence, $\im \gamma$ has $\frac{p^n -1}{p-1}$ elements. As $N$ is onto $F^\times$, $\ker N$ also has $\frac{p^n-1}{p-1}$ elements. That is $\im \gamma = \ker N$.

Now let $f \in \ker N = \im\gamma$. There is $g \in F^\times$ with $\gamma(g) = f$, that is $g^{p-1} = f$.